# Upgrade Angular 2 to angular 4 failed

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-upgrade

I upgraded from angular 2 to angular 4 and now I'm getting an error. I copied the text from [this](https://progblog.io/How-to-upgrade-to-Angular-4/) 
i.e.

`npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save`

Now I'm getting this error when I run npm start Please assist

`

> product-management@1.0.0 start C:\Users\dp9\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NG\NG UI
>
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(70,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'main' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(81,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'parent' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(82,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'children' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type 'NodeModule[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(102,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(263,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(371,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'stdout' must be of type 'WritableStream', but here has type 'WriteStream'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(372,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'stderr' must be of type 'WritableStream', but here has type 'WriteStream'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(373,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'stdin' must be of type 'ReadableStream', but here has type 'ReadStream'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(422,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'platform' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'Platform'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(580,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(580,50): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SlowBuffer'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(604,22): error TS2415: Class 'EventEmitter' incorrectly extends base class 'internal'.
>   Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
>         Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(624,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(769,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(824,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'addressType' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number | "udp4" | "udp6"'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(827,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1510,17): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CompleterResult'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(1547,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(2911,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3108,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'pfx' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | Buffer[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3109,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | any[] | string[] | Buffer'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3111,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3112,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3113,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'crl' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3115,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'honorCipherOrder' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'boolean'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3118,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'NPNProtocols' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string[] | Buffer'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3135,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3137,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3138,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type '(string | Buffer)[]', but here has type 'string | Buffer | (string | Buffer)[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3377,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'padding' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'number'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3382,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'padding' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'number'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3429,22): error TS2420: Class 'Readable' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadableStream'.
>   Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => Readable' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReadableStream; (): ReadableStream; }'.
>         Type 'Readable' is not assignable to type 'ReadableStream'.
>      Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
>             Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
>               Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>   node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3512,22): error TS2420: Class 'Writable' incorrectly implements interface 'WritableStream'.
>   Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
>         Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>   node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3622,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3705,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3727,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(3727,18): error TS2420: Class 'Domain' incorrectly implements interface 'NodeJS.Domain'.
>
> Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
>         Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(4019,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(78,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(234,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(516,9): error TS2502: 'BuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(517,9): error TS2502: 'SlowBuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(518,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(518,50): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SlowBuffer'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(580,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
>
> Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(591,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ServerResponse' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(621,22): error TS2320: Interface 'ClientRequest' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable'.
>
> Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Writable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'addListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'emit' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'on' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'prependListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'prependOnceListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(647,22): error TS2320: Interface 'IncomingMessage' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable'.
>
> Named property 'removeListener' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Readable' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(698,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(743,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1004,22): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CompleterResult'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1044,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1323,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Socket' and 'EventEmitter'.
>
> Named property 'removeListener' of types 'Socket' and 'EventEmitter' are not identical.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(1886,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2188,18): error TS2420: Class 'Readable' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadableStream'.
>
> Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => Readable' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReadableStream; (): ReadableStream; }'.
>         Type 'Readable' is not assignable to type 'ReadableStream'.
>           Property 'isPaused' is missing in type 'Readable'.
>   typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2211,18): error TS2420: Class 'Writable' incorrectly implements interface 'WritableStream'.
>
> Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
>         Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>           Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>             Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>   typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2229,18): error TS2420: Class 'Duplex' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadWriteStream'.
>
> Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => Duplex' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReadWriteStream; (): ReadWriteStream; }'.
>         Type 'Duplex' is not assignable to type 'ReadWriteStream'.
>           Property 'isPaused' is missing in type 'Duplex'.
>   typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2250,18): error TS2420: Class 'Transform' incorrectly implements interface 'ReadWriteStream'.
>
> Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => Transform' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReadWriteStream; (): ReadWriteStream; }'.
>         Type 'Transform' is not assignable to type 'ReadWriteStream'.
>           Property 'isPaused' is missing in type 'Transform'.
>   typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2343,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2365,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Domain'.
>
> typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2365,18): error TS2420: Class 'Domain' incorrectly implements interface 'NodeJS.Domain'.
>
> Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
>         Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>   typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(2625,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall typings. Typescript types are now managed by npm under the @types namespace:

```
npm uninstall --save typings
```

Also, delete the typings subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

To update from Angular 2 to Angular 4 please follow this steps:

**1** - Ensure you don't use extends OnInit, or use extends with any lifecycle event. Instead use implements `<lifecycle event>`.

**2** - Update all of your dependencies to version 4 and the latest TypeScript using

Mac/Linux

```
npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@4.0.0 typescript@latest --save
```

Windows

```
 npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next @angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save
```

**3** - If you use animations in your application, you should import BrowserAnimationsModule from @angular/platform-browser/animations in your App NgModule.

**4** - Rename your template tags to ng-template.

**5** - If you want to validate your forms add ngNativeValidate because angular 4 added novalidate attribute to all forms

---

if you still having some issues try to update [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and Typescript npm `install -g typescript@latest`

If none of that helped please update your Angular CLI to the latest version

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and generate a new Angular 4 project using `ng new newProject` and move your logic and templates to the new app.